# How to scan all open source libraries used in a project?

Tags: android, android-studio, shared-libraries

I want to scan all the libraries used in the android project. So that I can mention those libraries in a list whenever I remove or add new libraries in my project.

Like I added some libraries in-app dependencies and i want all of them to list down with their version name on one screen. So that I can mention used libraries with their licences in-app.

I want to identify that process in an automated way. So that whenever I add or remove the library from Gradle it will reflect the same on app.

Comment: Please explain what you have tried so far, and give an example of desired result. It will help those who try to help you.

Comment: @LudvigH please check again now  I explained a little bit more  about my question

Answer (score 7):

https://github.com/mikepenz/AboutLibraries seems to be better than the Google tools.

```
implementation "com.mikepenz:aboutlibraries-core:7.1.0"
implementation "com.mikepenz:aboutlibraries:7.1.0"
```

Answer (score 1):

Google has a plugin called `play-services-oss-licenses`.

The plugin even offers an activity to launch to show to the user all of them.

**Steps:**

- Add in your root gradle file:

```
classpath 'com.google.android.gms:oss-licenses-plugin:0.10.1'
```

- Add the plugin into your main module's gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.android.gms.oss-licenses-plugin'
```

- Add the library itself in your application's dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-oss-licenses:17.0.0'
```

- Launch the activity by calling:

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, OssLicensesMenuActivity.class));
```

Find more and how it works at the official documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/opensource).

Comment: 0.10.1 version is broken, 0.9.5 used to work but gave a warning about using a deprecated method that was removed in Jan 2020, so now does not work. The problem with 0.10.1 should be fixed in the next release but that has not been released yet.

Comment: @Andrew wasn't aware that it's broken. I haven't used it for awhile. Do you have an issuetracker link to look after?

Comment: One of many https://github.com/google/play-services-plugins/issues/119

Answer (score -2):

You can check all the libraries used in the android project using Analyzer APK optiopn.

Check Analyzer APK in Android Studio- you will be given a prompt to select your APK from the filesystem.

[image]

Comment: APK analyzer shows only APK content. There is no information about libraries inside. Especially if APK is obfuscated with ProGuard or R8.